# Area under curve within a particular time window

Tags: operational-amplifier, analog, integrator

[image: Curve1]

I am trying to make an analog circuit which would measure the area under the curve of a periodic signal within a certain time window (say, t2 and t3 in the image). I expect different voltages(say 50-500 mV) within that particular time (say 100 us) and want to compare the area in that interval with a threshold value later. I think an integrator should be suitable for the purpose, where after providing a cumulative value during the particular time, it will reset to zero. Is the idea correct and if yes how to design the circuit?

P.S. This is my first post. I hope the info is adequate. If not please let me know, I will add whatever is required.

Edit 1:[image: Curve1]
[image: Curve2]

Just to be even more clear. These are the envelopes of the two signals I am dealing with. The intial part of the signals are the same. Then the voltage changes for a certain time and it decays to zero. I am trying to compare these two.

Comment: You logic is correct. Check this out https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/opamp/opamp_6.html

Comment: t2 and t3 are in the middle of somewhere. how would you determine the exact start time of sampling. OK, the end is start_time+(t3-t2), but  start_time???

Comment: I plan to gate the signal in the integral time interval using a voltage controlled switch or transistor. Then the integrator will have non zero input within t2 and t3. t2 will be periodic every 150 us say.

Comment: if you need accurate, you must define error tolerances for integration, tolerances, leakage or bias current, or drift and reset error etc

Comment: I hope you know how to trigger the integration start/stop accurately and have a relevant reference, (offset)

Comment: Hard-ish problem.  You might save time by going to a digital approach.

Comment: @scott The microcontroller I have, has got a sampling time of 10ms. So I can't go the digital way, however I agree it would have been easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sampling can be acheived using sample / hold circuit. Since you don't want to hold anything, then you don't need a hold capacitor. Then you pass the output of S/H circuit to the integrator circuit. So youshould have Sample->Integrate->Hold (evaluate result)->Reset,....

S/H
[image]

Integrate/Reset
[image]

EDIT:

A good example:

https://digi.lib.ttu.ee/i/file.php?DLID=7459&t=1

[image]

http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/sbfs003/sbfs003.pdf

Keep in mind that you need an extra inverting op-amp if you need a positive voltge output.

Comment: note: capacitor should not be cheap ceramic but NPO type or plastic. and input bias will create offset unless matched R's.

Comment: Lot of hardware to replace a fifty cent microcontroller

Comment: Thanks you for the resources @Marko. I had handled the sampling problem but didn't think about the reset. Do you think I can use BJts for switching? Any major drawbacks I should keep in mind?

Comment: @SappyM Note that since you're using a sampling system, anti-alias filtering might be appropriate

Answer (score 1):

### Additional advice

Part of the challenge of partial integration is to define;

a) when the event starts ends
- e.g. derivative threshold , fixed time, or precision integral before event, etc
- use precision comparators or timers
b) integrate with respect to what reference?
- let Vdc at t=t2 be the 0V ref? or absolute 0Vdc
c) define accuracy or Signal to Noise Ratio SNR or std deviation error ( 3 sigma)
[image]

### Potential issues

-Sample & Hold caps can drift (ie integrate bias current so choose FET inputs)
-Residual error after dump switch  needs time for RdsOn*C,
-Ceramic capacitors have analog memory (except NPO) for S&H
-Plastic caps are ideal hgh tolerances may need calibration
-Some switches have feedthru capacitance of control pulse edges to cap.

-Choose gain to optimize resolution for ADC and amplify the signal and lower impedance to eliminate loading errors or if OK, amplify with integrator.
- e.g. 500mV for 20us for **Ic=CdV/dt** if Ic=1mA then 500mV/1mA is 500 Ohm load
- to amplify to 5V above is maximum, C = Ic * dt/dV = 1mA * 20us/5V = 4nF

Comment: Thank you for the insight. I will try making it work. In case of anomalies I can't identify, will get back to you.

Comment: Btw if you don't mind me asking, what tool did you use to superimpose the two images on each other? Looks cool..:)

Comment: PSP7 supports paste to new layer with transparency

Answer (score 0):

Gate the input signal with an analogue switch (triggered at \$t_2\$) and feed the gated signal to an integrator held in reset until \$t_2\$. At \$t_3\$, sample the output of the integrator then reset the integrator and open the analogue switch until event \$t_2\$ happens again. Rinse and repeat.

Make sure that when event \$t_3\$ arises, you provide enough sample time to charge your sampling capacitor. Buffer that capacitor voltage before connecting ongoing circuits to it. If necessary invert the buffered output to get a "value" that is positive.